# Disabling a script within another when enemy reaches target?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I have my enemy disable a script once it reaches a target player? I want to reference this script called Casting under my GameManager in my code. When I disable it my player can still cast even once the enemy is right over the target player. Is there a function that's preventing this?

```
public class aiEnemy : MonoBehaviour, IPooledObject {

public float lookRadius = 40f;

public Casting stop;

Transform target;
UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent agent;

Rigidbody theRigidBody;

void Start(){
    target = PlayerManager.instance.player.transform;
    agent = GetComponent<UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent>();
}


void Update(){
    float distance = Vector3.Distance (target.position, transform.position);
    if (distance <= lookRadius)
    {
        agent.SetDestination (target.position);

        if (distance <= agent.stoppingDistance)
        {
            FaceTarget ();
        }

        if (distance < 1f) // or some distance
        {
            stop.enabled = false;
        }
    }

}

void FaceTarget()
{
    Vector3 direction = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;
    Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (new Vector3 (direction.x, 0, direction.z));
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (transform.rotation, lookRotation, Time.deltaTime * 5f);
}


// Use this for initialization
public void OnObjectSpawn () {


    //myRender = GetComponent<Renderer> ();
    theRigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();



}

void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere (transform.position, lookRadius);
}
```

}

Comment: You can use gameObject.SetActive(false)

Comment: @captainCrazy but what if they still want the player to be able to move around and do anything else?

Comment: To get this right, you have the above script on an enemy and you want to disable a script on the player or is that script also on that enemy? You say that the script is still running even with the `stop.enabled = false`, correct? If so, did you look in the inspector (on runtime) to verify that the script is actually getting disabled?

Comment: I checked the inspector and the character can still Cast. the above script is on the enemy while the one I want to disable is on my game manager. @GunnarB.

Comment: Sounds to me like the reference to the other script is not correct. On runtime, click on the field `stop` in the inspector, that should highlight the object in hierarchy that the referenced script is on.

Comment: I decided to make my GameManager a prefab. Although I drag it into my `EnemyAI` script `public stop` in the inspector. I also notice because I am item pooling the enemy prefab has the right `Casting` script in the inspector.  Once it goes active the script is no longer in the inspector.

Comment: ...well, yes. When you destroy the spell and create a new one, that reference needs to be updated.